# Expectation Values of Operators on QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I've been given that the expectation value of an observable associated with an operator, Q is

$$\left<\Psi|Q|\Psi\right> $$

Feel like this is a pretty basic question but is the psi in this case the collapsed wave function? If it is, I don't understand how you can get a distribution of values associated with the operator, which lead to an expectation value.

Comment: The distribution comes from the fact that there are a variety of wave functions (usually stationary states) from which to choose. These are all solutions to a Schrodinger equation with an associated Hamiltonian. Wave function collapse refers to solutions that are superposition of stationary states and collapse occurs after a measurement is made resulting in one of the stationary state eigenvalues.

Comment: So psi in this case is a linear superposition of all these stationary states? As in it's the wave function before a measurement is made?
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: So something like:

psi = sum((c_i)(psi_i))           (third postulate).

Where c_i is a complex constant, and Psi_i are all possible collapsed wave functions
Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: I would refer to them as stationary states rather than collapsed wave functions. It is better for beginning QM   students to avoid talking about wave function collapse as it gets into philosophical questions too soon.

Answer (score 2):

$|\Psi\rangle$ is the state of the system prior to the measurement.

$\langle\Psi|Q|\Psi\rangle$ is the expectation value of the observable $Q$ in the state $|\Psi\rangle$.  Essentially this means that if you had a billion copies of the same system, all in the state $|\Psi\rangle$, and measured $Q$ in all of them, the average of your results would be $\langle\Psi|Q|\Psi\rangle$.

Comment: Okayy, think that makes sense. 
So psi can collapse into many different eigenfunctions, and <psi|Q|psi> gives you the eigenvalue associated with the most common state that psi collapses into

Comment: No. The expectation value is the average of the eigenvalues, weighted by the probability that the state is measured to be in the corresponding eigenstate.

Comment: If Q takes the values -1/2 with probability 0.5 and +1/2 with probability 0.5, then the expectation value is zero despite the fact that no individual measurement will ever yield a value of 0.